# error al ejecutar comando npm start con node js proyecto con conexion a bd sql server

Tags: nodejs

intento hacer una api para obtener datos de una base de datos sql server pero al ejecutar el comando npm start para

[image: imagen del error]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Seguro en los módulos no tienes incluido ese que se reseña en el error. Sin ver el código, es imposible que recibas una buena respuesta. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el error instalando las dependencias, comando: npm instal (dependencia)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]